# How to install Java file into windows services

Tags: windows, distributed-computing

How do I install Java file into Windows services and that Java file should be running when the PC is running. Because I have to know the IP address and free spaces of hard disk in cloud PC's (same network).

Comment: i would prefer to make a rough technology review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Java Service Wrapper. It enables a Java Application to be run as a Windows Service or UNIX Daemon.

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You could use srvany and can do java -jar filename.jar 
First you can create a service using sc windows command to run srvany and then input the arguments as described above.
Search for srvany on google its pretty much everywhere out there
Let me know if you need any explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

I have very good experience with [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/index.html). Their [procrun utility](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) is written for exactly that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the most success with this [Yet Another Java Service Wrapper](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/).  Despite the name, it also allows you to setup other programs as services.  I also found it the easiest to setup with a script; many others require a GUI interface.